# Rust: Implemented Display on Formatter for BufferMemory but for some reason won't take

Tags: rust

currently I'm trying to debug a problem but in order to do that I'm trying to print out some information so I figured I would go and implement Display for my BufferMemory. I keep getting `` std::option::Option<&memory::BufferMemory>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display ``
`` std::option::Option<&memory::BufferMemory>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter `` even though I'm pretty sure I've implemented it here. What could I be doing wrong?

```
/// A simple buffer of memory for MemorySystem
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct BufferMemory{
    pub memory: Vec<u8>,
}

impl fmt::Display for BufferMemory {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let formatted_vec = String::from_utf8(self.memory).unwrap();
        write!(f, "{}", formatted_vec)
    }
}
/// The system for tracking all memory within the VM
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MemorySystem{
    map: HashMap<u32, BufferMemory>
}
```

and I'm trying to access the value I'm looking at like such.

```
        println!("result: {}", self.map.get(&(address & 0xFFFF0000)));
```

where address is a u32 value

Comment: `self.map.get(…)` is an `Option<T>` because there might not be such element. `Option<T>` doesn't implement `Display`, but it does implement `Debug`. Do you mean to use `Debug` here?

Comment: perhaps? I'm still getting my bearings on Rust. Should the Debug trait be added to the BufferMemory bit or to the map itself?

Comment: Yea you were right I was looking for Debug trait